# Ответ с помощью бота обратной связи

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Пробую написать бота обратной связи. Создал бота, создал группу в которую бот пересылает сообщения отправленные народом. Прикрутил к сообщениям кнопку ответить, а дальше тупик - не понимаю, как сделать так, что бы нажимая кнопку ответить человеку пришел ответ от имени бота в тот чат в котором он начал общаться.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from random import randint

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token="")
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(Command(commands=['start']))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply ("Hello!")


@dp.message(content_types=['text'])
async def forward_message(message:types.Message):
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="Ответить",
        callback_data="answer")
    )
    await bot.send_message(-976355707,f'{message.text}\n Отправил: {message.from_user.username}',
    reply_markup=builder.as_markup())


@dp.callback_query(text="answer")
async def answer(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await ?????????


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Ну или это может как то по другому реализуется? (естественно потом сделаю что бы кнопка ответить пропадала, что бы понимать на что ответил, а на что нет. Мне бы принцип понять...